# Qtspim: generating an array and changing value, syntax error

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, mips, qtspim

I am trying to create a simple program that generates an array a with 5 values , and adds 3 to a[2].
I want to simulate it into QTspim
This is the program:

```
.data
a: .word 1,2 ,3 ,4 ,5

la $to, a #put the adress of a0 into register t0
lw $t1, 8($to) # put the value of a2 into register 1
addi $t2, $t1, 3
li $v0,10
syscall
```

And this is the errow message I get:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a space after a comma, so `1, 2` not `1,2`.  Also, you need a `.text` directive before the code and a `main:` label right after the `.text` directive.  The register is `$t0`, not `$to`.

Comment: really? does the space matter? okay i''ll ckeck it

Answer (score 0):

QtSpim's parser is a bit picky, so fix your array declaration:

```
a: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Then you'll have to open the `.text` (code) section and define your `main` label before your first instruction:

```
.text
.globl main
main:
```

And you'll have to fix your typos of `$to` -> `$t0`.

Comment: The `.globl main` directive is harmless but unnecessary for QtSPIM.